# Ubuntu 13.04 Installation on Lenovo U410 dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, system-installation, lenovo

I've just bought an Lenovo U410 and want to dual boot Ubuntu 13.04 (or the LTS, not that worried) and the included Windows 8. I've seen that previously the SSD cache/Raid arrangement of the U410 causes problems for dual booting, but all the threads I've seen are about Win7 and 12.10.

My question is is there any difference in trying to work with 13.04 and Windows 8? And does anyone have a step-by-step for how to do this (a verbose one because it's a while since I've installed Ubuntu on anything!).

Many thanks
Marcus.

Answer (score 1):

Each new version of Ubuntu is working better with UEFI. Also the vendors are fixing the bugs they had in UEFI as they only tested with Windows.

If your model is an Ultrabook, you have UEFI as a new way to install, dual video which may require some effort and Intel SRT or RAID that adds issues.

If you are primarily a Windows user you proably want to keep the Intel SRT as it provides some speed up to Windows. Some with larger SSD just install Ubuntu to SSD and have a faster Ubuntu but then Windows is just running from hard drive like Windows 7 did.

You must turn off the permanent hibernation or fast boot and remove the RAID meta-data. Turning Intel SRT back on will create the RAID on the SSD if that is what you want. 
Always backup efi partition and your Windows install first. Make a Windows repair flash drive.

Fast Startup off/hibernation
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html
Force removal of hiberfil from Ubuntu
http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/01/mount-windows-8-partition-ubuntu-hybrid-boot/

Remove RAID:

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb
```

Bumblebee:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

Shows install with screen shots.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot. required for UEFI & grub bug fixes

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair